# Unity Text mesh pro custom Font issue

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

Following an upgrade from Unity 2020.3.36f to 2023.2.3f1, I've encountered problems with custom fonts in Text Mesh Pro. The texts using custom fonts aren't displaying correctly, whereas the default Text Mesh Pro fonts work fine. Even after downloading new fonts, the issue persists. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem with custom fonts not displaying properly in Text Mesh Pro after the Unity upgrade?

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: I assume you've created the Font Asset from your original font file. Have you tried deleting the (apparently) corrupted Font Asset and creating a new one?